# Quark, antiquark pair doubts

Tags: quarks, pair-production, mesons

When a quark, antiquark pair is created by high energy photons, do they glue together as mesons or is another pair created to hold them together, so there is a total of four particles?

Comment: Can you clarify what process you mean? Maybe draw the tree level diagram.

Comment: Following QCD both quarks would glue with another quark or anti-quark, but i dont know if a qurk/anti-quark produced by a photon pair production would glue one with the other or if they would create a quark for themselves

Comment: A quark-atiquark pair produced by a on-shell photon must be virtual and can't form a meson without further interaction. But a photon that is just the right amount off-shell can fluctuate to, say, a $\pi^0$. Frankly it is hard to be precise about this stuff with words, which is a good enough reason for using Feynman diagrams to describe it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, one has to use Feynman diagrams in order to easily understand quantum number conservation and energy momentum conservation.

Let us take the simple case of a high energy photon creating an e+e- pair. [Here is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Electron-Positron_nuclear_Pair_production_Feynman_Diagram.gif) the Feynman diagram of an incoming gamma ray creating an e+e- pair:

[image: gammae+e-]

which conserves energy, momentum and lepton quantum numbers. The incoming real photon ( on mass shell photon) interacts with the field  of a nucleus through virtual photon (off mass shell photon)

As quarks and antiquarks are charged, the same diagram can be written for a pair of them , a q+q-. Except that more constraints enter, because quarks cannot be free due to the strength of the strong interaction, and they are virtual  . In addition quark number is a conserved quantity (1/3 of baryon number) and has to be conserved.

In the pantheon of hadronic resonances there exist the [vector mesons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_meson), i.e . spin one hadrons made up by a quark antiquark pair. Their photo production [has been observed](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/9910038), which means that the incoming quark binds with the outgoing antiquark and makes a vector meson which also conserves the spin one of the  incoming photon.

[image]

Figure 1The Feynman diagrams for photoproduction of vector mesons (a)... - Scientific Figure on ResearchGate. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/269035100_fig10_Figure-1The-Feynman-diagrams-for-photoproduction-of-vector-mesons-a-and-oN-final-state [accessed Jul 5, 2016]

More complicated photo production diagrams can be envisaged where  two quark antiquark pairs are needed to balance them, but the simplest one, vector meson production, goes through only two , a quark and antiquark.